# In a C# GUI program how do you move a tab control to the front on the click of an object?

Tags: c#, winforms

In a C# GUI program how do you move a tab control to the front on the click of an object?

I have a picture box on the main tab, when the user clicks on the picture box, I want the second tab to be pulled forward.

Visual Studio 2005

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you trying to select a different tab or bring a TabControl in front of a different control?

If the former, write `tabControl.SelectedTab = someTabPage` in the picture box's Click event.

If the latter, write `tabControl.BringToFront()`.

Comment: Doh, beat me to it...  Good explanation on both methods.

Answer (score 1):

You want to handle the [`Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx) event on the control (add a handler to [`Control.OnClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick.aspx)) containing the picture, and if you have `tabControl` and `myTabPage` is the tab page that you want to be selected after the click, you would use [`TabControl.SelectedPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx):

```
tabControl.SelectedTab = myTabPage;
```

In particular, since you refer to the "second tab" then you probably want

```
tabControl.SelectedTab = tabControl.TabPages[1];
```

Comment: Actually, `OnClick` is a function, not an event.  You want the `Click` event.

Answer (score 0):

To select a different tab, set the `SelectedTab` index from your handler:

```
// select the second tab in the control
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[1];
```